# Not able to get python version even after setting pyenv global version

Tags: python, pyenv

I have installed pyenv-win for windows, also removed the normal python path from PATH environment variable.

Then, I have installed 2 versions of python(3.6.8 and 3.8.0) using "**pyenv install** ".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLeTI.png)

Applied pyenv global version as running the command "**pyenv global 3.6.8**", when I run "**pyenv versions**", it is showing 3.6.8 is the global version.

But when I run "python --version" nothing is getting displayed and so I can't run any python file". I have also run "**pyenv rehash**" as well. Also, I have added /.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims and bin as well in the PATH environment variable.

I need your help here. Any leads would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you run https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win#finish-the-installation

Comment: yes @StefanWang, I am able to check "pyenv --version" and also "pyenv rehash", but not sure what rehash is doing, it is not returning anything, and also it completes very quickly.

Comment: ohh !!, now, it's working.
But, I really did that because earlier also "pyenv versions" and "pyenv rehash" were working for me and  also was able to set global version, the only issue is when I run "python --version" nothing comes.

But now it is working, all I did is just ran the "follow the installation" steps again.
Thank you @StefanWang

Comment: nice to hear that

Comment: For me a restart of the shell I was working in did the trick. Somehow the global instruction didn't take effect before.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you sould disable some aliases (see step n°3)

Here is how I installed pyenv-win, i had the same issue:

1 - Uninstall Python (your current version when you type the command python -V)

2 - Install pyenv-win and add it to the PATH (here are some optional steps to install it via chocolatey, which adds it directly to the PATH)

2.2 - Install chocolatey

2.3 - In an administrator powershell run: `choco install pyenv-win`

3 - Start menu (windows key) -> Manage application execution aliases -> disable aliases related to python
[image: here it's in french but it should be similar]

4 - install the desired python version via pyenv: `pyenv install DESIRED VERSION NUMBER`

5- run `pyenv rehash`

6 - set it as global `pyenv global DESIRED VERSION NUMBER`

7 - you sould see the desired version by running the command `python -V`